# Java arraylist to array, array to string error

Tags: java, arraylist, tostring, toarray

I have to read data from `text.txt` file, but I have strange error, my output is: `[Ljava.lang.String;@5f0a94c5`.

The contents of `text.txt` file:

```
test::test.1::test.2
test2::test2.1::test2.2
test3::test3.1::test3.2
```

The code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class test {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"))) {
            String CurrLine;

            while((CurrLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                data.add(CurrLine);
            }
            String[] dataArray = new String[data.size()];
            data.toArray(dataArray);
            Arrays.toString(dataArray);
            System.out.println(dataArray);


        } catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("FNFE");
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("IOE");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dataArray));
```

In your code, `Arrays.toString(dataArray);` does nothing as you don't do anything with its returned value.

BTW, as @ZouZou pointed out, you can also print your `ArrayList` directly:

```
System.out.println(data);
```

Comment: can i use String arr = Arrays.toString(dataArray)); ?

Comment: Yes. You can use it and print `arr`.

Comment: @user3104545 Why don't you directly print your list ?`System.out.println(data);`

Comment: Glad I could help. You can accept it if you find it helpful :)

Comment: i need wait for 30 secs for this)

Answer (score 1):

Your code : `System.out.println(dataArray);` will output the hashcode value for the object dataArray. Any array in Java does not override `equals()` method. As a result, when you try to print the value of the array object, `java.lang.Object.equals()` method is invoked which prints the hashcode of the object .

Instead try using `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dataArray));`